# Nodejs: creating EventEmitter object

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. I came across these two ways as follow for instantiating `EventEmitter` class as follows -

```
const events = require('events');

const e = new events.EventEmitter();
const e1 = new events();

console.log(e)
console.log(e1)
```

How come both `e` and `e1` are instantiated from `EventEmitter`? Which is the right way? Am I m missing anything here?

Comment: It's the same. In order to instantiate `e1` you need to `require: const {EventEmitter} = require('events');` The way you did it `EventEmitter` is `undefined`

Comment: I mistakenly put the wrong snippet in the question. Updated the snippet now.

Answer (score 2):

According to
[Events module line#68](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L68)
and
[Events module line#73](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L73)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE1M4.png)

> node -p "events.EventEmitter === events"

This will get the result of **true**, which means "events.EventEmitter" and "events" in your code can be used to instantiate EventEmitter.

Comment: Ohh, I see this is done for backward compatibility. But I wonder how the circular dependency is handled in the case of EventEmitter.EventEmitter = EventEmitter in the events module

Comment: The 'source' of EventEmitter is at [line65](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L65). What [line73](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L73) does is to add a property called 'EventEmitter' to the 'EventEmitter' function, and the value of this property refers back to the 'EventEmitter' function. Hope that the comment is helpful.

Comment: But doesn't that create infinite recursions when a property 'EventEmitter' is added to the 'EventEmitter' function, and the value of this property refers back to the 'EventEmitter' function?

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, may I know more about what the "infinite recursions" means?

Comment: I have created a similar example to demonstrate. Please try the following code in the browser console. 
function foo(){}
foo.foo = foo
console.dir(foo)
Please have a look at the nested foo properties of the foo function.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the nested 'foo' property?

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code, you need to define `EventEmitter`

so that you can create instance `new EventEmitter();`

```
const events = require('events');

const EventEmitter = require('events'); // correct in your code 

const e = new events.EventEmitter();

const e1 = new EventEmitter();

console.log(e)
console.log(e1)
```

> Which is the right way

they are both the correct way and it is up to you in which way you want to write

> I personally prefer `e1` because it looks clean

[example](https://runkit.com/imsingh/eventemitter)

### as you update your question

```
const events = require('events');

const e = new events.EventEmitter();
const e1 = new events();

console.log(e)
console.log(e1)
```

> e1 is a clean way but Constructor function name should be
>   Captial, convention in Javascript is to only capitalize constructors

```
 const Events = require('events');
 const e1 = new Events();
```